# c# dllimport question

Tags: c#, dllimport

I am iporting a method from an external dll and have the following code:

```
[DllImport("test.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern TabPage CreateGUI();
```

and to call this:

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(CreateGUI());
```

I get the error saying that CreateGui cannot be located within the dll.  The CreateGui method has been declared public and static within the dll?  Anybody any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: is test.dll a .net DLL or some Legacy DLL?

Comment: public? you're trying to "import" a .Net assembly? Isn't DllImport for use with Interop/COM assemblies only?

Comment: Okay, cheers.  It is .net, I didn't realise this was for unmanaged code/com etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the method returns a TabPage it is a .NET method, hence it is a .NET Assembly. Then you should not import it with DllImport, but add the dll as a reference in your project.

**Edit:**
If you want to load a .NET Assembly dynamically you need to load it with [`Assembly.LoadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx) and then find your types with [`Assembly.GetTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx).

Comment: I can't add as a reference as the dll should be loaded dynamically, this will be a plug in architecture, which each module (dll) loading only if shipped with the client.

Comment: @Darren Young, I updated my answer with dynamic loading of .NET Assemblies